# Ganeymed-ssh2 SCP issue-- need to copy file from my desktop to remote unix server

Tags: java, unix

Ganeymed-ssh2 SCP issue-- need to copy file from my desktop to remote Unix server. Can anybody tell me even if it is possible?. I am facing problems with connection object, do not know what host-name i should give there if i want to get connection object for my desktop machine:

Connection conn = new Connection("?????");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i Do figure out myself. I used SCPClient as below:

1. First make a connection to remoteHost as :

   ```
   Connection conn = new Connection(remoteHostNameOrIP);
   try {
       conn.connect();

   } catch (Exception e) {

       System.out.println("Message is : -" + e.getMessage());
       return "unable to connect";
   }
   ```
2. Then just use SCP client as :

   ```
    SCPClient scpc = conn.createSCPClient();
    scpc.put(sourceLocalDesktopFileLocation, DestinationRemoteFileLocation, Mode);
   ```